# Application Crash when remove ARC in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

my application was based on ARC and i removed ARC for some reason.now application crash in UICollectionView i dont understand how to release object which is img_array here

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

{
    isShown = false;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    img_ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    img_ary= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png", nil];
    [self collectioncreate];
    img1_ary=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    img1_ary=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"small-slider-images.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-images.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-images.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-images.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-images.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png",@"small-slider-image-2.png", nil];

    nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   // nameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"Top 5",@"Call",@"car",@"Buy",@"View Tutorial",@"MOI",@"Terms & Conditions",@"Private Policy",nil];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Top 5"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Call"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Car"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Buy"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"View Tutorial"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"MOI"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Terms & Conditions"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Private Policy"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"About Us"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Corporate Account"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"4th Motor Envioroment"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Help & FAQ"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Contact Us"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Track Your Order"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Sell on $ Motor"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"Adjust your Car"];

    UIImage *searchFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-1.png"]
                                 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 17, 10)];

    [search_bar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchFieldImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];



    //[self createScrollView1];
    //[self createButton1];

}


-(void)collectioncreate1
{

    cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"caracell" bundle:nil];
    [collectionview registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"caracell"];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(279, 244)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [collectionview setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    collectionview.delegate=self;
    collectionview.dataSource=self;
    [collectionview reloadData];
}


-(void)collectioncreate
{

    cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"carecell" bundle:nil];
    [collectionview registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"carecell"];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(279, 244)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [collectionview setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    collectionview.delegate=self;
    collectionview.dataSource=self;
    [collectionview reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 10;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [img_ary count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //     [self resetIdleTimer];
    carecell * cell = (carecell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"carecell" forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    if(cell==nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"carecell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    cell.car_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[img_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    **********************AT This point app Crash *********************
    return cell;

}
```

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you Know the Difference Between `NSMutableArray`  or `NSArray` ?

Comment: yeah but even crashing application when i use NSArray

Comment: @8unty i dont understand where to release obj?

Comment: Why would you turn _off_ ARC? You are going to have to insert manual memory management code _everywhere_ in your app. This is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

This code is incorrect:

```
img_ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
img_ary= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png", nil];
```

It currently creates *two* NSMutableArrays (two calls to `alloc`), leaks the first one, and doesn't retain the second one.

You should make one NSMutableArray, and keep a strong reference to it by retaining it (either via `alloc` or `retain`, but not both)

(edit)

Also, you really should probably just use ARC. It's quite helpful.

Comment: i put nonatomic,strong in @property.but crash .and when i take arc then it run why?

Comment: but when i use arc it crash in device

Comment: Unless you use self.img_ary or [self setImg_ary:], then you're not using your property at all. What you declared it as makes no difference unless you actually use it.

Comment: If your code is crashing with ARC turned on, and also crashing with ARC turned off, you should probably debug your code instead of turning ARC on and off.

Answer (score 0):

If your turing off ARC means,

Just do this.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *img_ary;
```

and in implementation.

```
self.img_ary= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png",@"car-image.png",@"image.png", nil];
```

And remove this line `img_ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`, it is waste in both ARC and Non-ARC.